# Return a view more than once or how to dynamically update the view

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, asp.net-core

I have a form with different string fields to be filled out and a submit button below.

The controller starts a runbook and return the result - this result can take some time dependent on the runbook complexity. I want to be able to immediately report back to user if the runbook was started successfully and then after a while return the status and output.

But MVC can only return the view once.

I want to achieve something similar to this:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Submit(Dictionary<string, string> inputs)
    {
        //Start runbook and return job
        var job = await _customAzureOperations.StartRunbook(_resourceGroup, _automationAccount, _runbookName, inputs);

        //return view
        if (job != null && job.Status == JobStatus.Completed)
        {
            TempData["JobStatus"] = "Success";
            return View("Index");

            //moving on.. HOW CAN I DO THIS?
            var result = await _customAzureOperations.GetResultsFromJob(job); //this could take a while

            TempData["JobResult"] = result;
            return View("Index");

        }
        else
        {
            return View("Index", TempData["JobStatus"] = "Error"); //todo: show exception etc.
        }

    }
```

Now the controller action of course does not make sense as you can't return after a return, but hope you can see where I'm going at :) How can I "report" back *before* returning the view?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is too broad, but generally speaking, you need to schedule the work to be run in the background (`IHostedService`, Hangfire, etc.). Then, you'll need to implement a SignalR hub and have your client connect to that and listen for a particular message and do something when it gets it, such as make an AJAX request (although you can return data as part of the message instead). When your job completes, you send that message through your hub, out to your clients.

Comment: Thanks, yes I was looking at SignalIR so ill give it a try and write here if I nail it. Just thought there were a more lighter way - seems like the m-v-c approach is very linear, but maybe I got it all backwards :)

Comment: Ok SignalR solved it, but I still need to invoke something to the caller client and not all clients
public async Task<IActionResult> Submit(string signalRconnectionId, Dictionary<string, string> inputs)
        {
            //Invoke signal to all clients
            await _signalHubContext.Clients.Client(signalRconnectionId).SendAsync("initSignal", "This is a message from server to this client: " + signalRconnectionId);